# Google+ ans FB login on asp .net 2.0 project

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I am upgrading login system for asp 2.0 website. 
I tried with with javascripts which fb and google provided, and they work! But im having trouble sending user data to server for another action without exposing them through post variables. 
Does anyone know some c# way to do this loggins? Or how to transfer securely data from javascript variables to c#

Thank you!

Comment: Define: "Secure data from javascript". Javascript is client side and so all you can do is send it over the wire.